# Windows "Open" function not working for .LIS files

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, windows-10-1809

I recently installed notepad++ on a Win 10 Enterprise machine and while I can open a file with the 'Edit with Notepad++' option in the right-click menu, double clicking or right clicking and selecting "Open" / "Open with..." does not do anything. I get not errors or popups. The cursor shows it's processing the request for half a second and then goes back to normal.

The machine is running on Win 10 Build 1809.

I have already tried the following:

- Reinstalling notepad++
- Installing an older version of the same program
- Rebooting the machine

I'm developing a bruise from the amount banging my head against a wall trying to solve this one folks.

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in a different text editor to determine if the problem is with N++ or the file?

Comment: If you right click on the *.LIS file and select "Properties", in the "General" tab, do you get a "Opens with:" "Change" button? If you do, can you change how it opens from there and set it to N++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an elevated CMD prompt type these commands:

```
Assoc .lis
```

That will give you the actual file type and will look similar to this:

```
.lis =lisfile
```

Take the actual file type and add it to this command**:

```
Ftype lisfile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1
```

**(Just make sure your NotePad++ is in the same directory as mine!)**

Comment: Hey there! This seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!